# SpringSecurity custom login functionality doesn't work with SpringBoot and REST api

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, authentication, spring-security

I try to implement login functionality with custom login page, but unfortunately it doesn't work.. I also can't find the reason why.. probably I don't exactly understand the SpringSecurity mechanism. It looks like submit button do nothing. My code below. I will be greatfull for help.

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test login page</h1>
    <form name="login" action="/login" method="post">
        User: <input type="text" name="username"/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
        <hr>
        <button id="loginAsGuest">Login as a guest</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("userguest").password("{noop}userguest").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/bookmarks-app/index.html", true)
                .failureUrl("/login.html")
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")
        );


    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunatell this did't resolve my problem.

Comment: What's not working ? When you login,  it gives you an error? Doesn't redirect you? Nothing happens?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Aug 15 21:35:16 CEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pointing out something.

**hasAnyRole** supports more than one role, so you can write something like this `.antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")`

if you put /** every rest service will trigger the role check, if you put just / only the / rest service will trigger the check.

Remove  `.antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()` and replace `.loginPage("/login.html")` with `.loginPage("/login").permitAll()`

In the end your config will look like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            //No need to add a LoginController.
            // Needed because if you don't put this, when you call the POST to login you will be redirected to the login.html page.
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/bookmarks-app/index.html", true)
            .failureUrl("/login.html").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")
    );
}
```

If your Login page it's in the resources, don't forget to configure the ResourceHandler correctly.

Sources:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html

[How to use Spring Security to custom login page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787219/how-to-use-spring-security-to-custom-login-page/54128237)

Comment: Unfortunately, it back me again to login page.

Comment: I tested the provided solution , was working for me, did you change something ?

Comment: I try the code directly as you described above. So probably I do sth wrong in other place... here is my repo on github: https://github.com/krzysztofskul/bookmarks-app

Comment: @krzysztofskul let me know if the fix (on github) works for you, it should cuz the code now it's exactly the same

Comment: It works now, thank you! Sorry for no response, I was sure I already answered.