# How to make multiple apps redirect to same login page hosting Google OAuth and make it redirect to corresponding app upon successful authentication?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have some web applications built with spring boot and react. Both react and spring boot servers  run in their corresponding container.

I want to build oauth based single sign on (SSO) functionality for all these applications. For example, if user goes to any of applications and try to login, it should redirect to the same page providing OAuth based SSO functionality (may be using google OAuth or facebook OAuth). Logging in once should login across all apps (and possibly logging out once should log out across all apps).

What all I found regarding OAuth2 in official docs is [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_making_the_home_page_public) example. It creates an application which configures the Spring security to redirect to google login and once the login is successful, it redirects back to index.html specified in the same application.

However, I already have multiple applications which I want all to redirect to single webpage which contains button "Login with Google" (along with other options like login with facebook and username / password). Upon successful google authentication, I want it to redirect to corresponding application which initiated the login.

**Q1.** Is it possible with some simple redirects? If yes how?

I did not found any tutorial explaining how to achieve this. I came across only [this](https://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2) tutorial which makes use of makes uses Keycloak Authorization server with spring boot to demonstrate login across two apps. But Keycloak is not the part of spring boot.

**Q2.** If answer to Q1 is no, then how can I achieve OAuth2 based SSO across multiple apps, with all of them redirecting to single login webpage and redirecting to corresponding app upon successful authentication? Can you please elaborate the process or point me to some tutorial?

**Update:** I came across [another post](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/02/15/single-sign-on-in-spring-boot-applications-with-spring-security-oauth/) which seem to explain the same but with now deprecated `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation.

Comment: How about a filter in the apps that invokes and / or redirects to the auth server?

Comment: So by auth server you mean custom implementation using [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/) spring project right? And to be precise, something like as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69577014/1317018), right? Also, the same answer says that SAML based SSO is preferable. It is talking about [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html) or [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/saml2.html) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Federated Identity sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver) is one of the samples available for Spring Authorization Server. It demonstrates how to configure Google and GitHub (you can also configure Facebook and others in a [similar way](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login#facebook-login)) as a 3rd party authentication or identity provider.

If you follow the instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples#federated-identity-sample) and run the `messages-client` (client) and `messages-resource` (resource server) in the samples directory, you can test out the entire flow.

So to answer your questions (hopefully simply):

1. Yes, using Spring Security OAuth2 client support and Spring Authorization Server as demonstrated in the samples mentioned above. If you're looking for examples of a javascript frontend, see [this branch](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/bff-demo/samples) (specifically the `angular-client` sample) and this [webinar](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) for more info on single-page apps and Spring Authorization Server.
2. N/A

Comment: Hi Steve, great pointers!!! I just have couple of questions, I have also come across [posts](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/10/09/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2-with-keycloak/) explaining using Keycloak for authorization server. **Q1.** How does Keycloak compares with Spring Authorization server?  **Q2.** Should one also use Spring Cloud (as explained in linked post) or we can do away with it?

Comment: Hi @Maha. Unfortunately I don't represent the Keycloak project so I can't comment too much on it, but you can read about it on their website. I'm not sure I understand the usage of Spring Cloud Gateway from skimming the article so I'd have to read it more thoroughly to understand the author's requirements, but Spring Cloud and SCG is definitely not required for Spring Authorization Server. There could be compelling use cases that combine them, but I don't have a list of those. That may be worth posting a separate question tagged spring-cloud or spring-cloud-gateway.